# How to register python microservices with my eureka server (spring boot)

Tags: python, spring-boot, microservices

Inorder to register microservices with eureka server we need to add following config in our microservice

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=${DISCOVERY_URL:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/
eureka.client.service-url.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=1
eureka.client.service-url.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=1
```

But i need to create microservice in python and to register with eureka server.
So how should i achieve?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Need to have REST implementation that follows  [Eureka-REST-operations](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations) . Below is a sample implementation that follow Eureka REST in Python.

Refer to full documentation at [Python client for Netflix Eureka](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/python-eureka)

```
from eureka.client import EurekaClient
import logging

logging.basicConfig()


ec = EurekaClient("MyApplication",
                  eureka_domain_name="test.yourdomain.net",
                  region="eu-west-1",
                  vip_address="http://app.yourdomain.net/",
                  port=80,
                  secure_vip_address="https://app.yourdomain.net/",
                  secure_port=443
)
print ec.get_zones_from_dns()
print ec.get_eureka_urls()
print ec.register()
print ec.update_status("UP")  # Or ec.register("UP")
print ec.heartbeat()
```

Answer (score 4):

The recommended github project by @AzizSM has not been updated in four years. A more recent project is https://github.com/keijack/python-eureka-client. It was last updated in November 2019.